# internationalization - translate urls or not

Tags: url, internationalization, seo, translation

I've found a lot of topics talcking about url schemes when going to international, the most common is the one which do :

- www.mysite.com/fr/products
- www.mysite.com/en/products
- www.mysite.com/es/products

Is is common or useful to do something like this?

- www.mysite.com/fr/produits
- www.mysite.com/en/products
- www.mysite.com/es/productos

ie translating the path as well as the page content.

Comment: wwww stands for... "wonderful world wide web"? "woefull world wide web"? "whichever works will win"? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Stack Overflow is the right forum for this, but here goes:

From a technical point of view, option 1 is probably the easiest to implement. If you are on any English-language page and need to link to, say, the Spanish version of the same page, all you need to do is take your URL and replace `/en/` by `/es/`.

So far I've seen this approach used practically everywhere... I cannot remember ever having seen option 2 in practice.

Comment: example for solution 2 :http://www.danone.com/ but I agree it is not frequently used. Actually my urls are in french so the question is : should I keep the french ones, or mirate all in english (better), or keep both (en and fr)